Asynchronous state change in React
I would like to understand the asynchronous nature of react state change. The below code is not working for me. As I expected, it should reset the form input fields after dispatching the corresponding action.
const AddBook = ({ book }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    author: '',
    thumbnail: '',
    price: '',
    rating: '',
    featured: false,
  });

  const [formMode, setFormMode] = useState('Add');

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (book) {
      setFormMode('Edit');
      setFormData({
        id: book.id,
        name: book.name,
        author: book.author,
        thumbnail: book.thumbnail,
        price: book.price,
        rating: book.rating,
        featured: book.featured,
      });
    }
  }, [book]);

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (book) {
      dispatch(editBookThunk(formData));
      return;
    }

    const bookData = {
      ...formData,
      featured: formData.featured ? true : false,
    };
    const { id, ...bookDataWithoutId } = bookData;
    dispatch(addBookThunk(bookDataWithoutId));

    setFormData({
      name: '',
      author: '',
      thumbnail: '',
      price: '',
      rating: '',
      featured: false,
    });
    setFormMode('Add');
  };

return (
<form> 
...
</form>
)

But if I reset the form before dispatching, everything works fine. The below code is perfectly working.
const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setFormData({
      name: '',
      author: '',
      thumbnail: '',
      price: '',
      rating: '',
      featured: false,
    });
    setFormMode('Add');

    if (book) {
      dispatch(editBookThunk(formData));
      return;
    }

    const bookData = {
      ...formData,
      featured: formData.featured ? true : false,
    };
    const { id, ...bookDataWithoutId } = bookData;
    dispatch(addBookThunk(bookDataWithoutId));
  };

I also noticed that, using async-await also does right job for me.

You cannot rely on the fact that something async does not complete before the next statement is executed. It's simply not true and not intended this way. So (async () => console.log('foo'))(); (() => console.log('bar'))() may print foo and bar in any order.

Setting state is not asynchronous in the way one typically expects async to work in JS.  For instance, if we have the below code in a React function component...
const [myState, setMyState] = useState(0)

function fooFunc(){
  setMyState((prev) => prev + 1)
  console.log(myState)
}


...fooFunc will never be able to set state and then immediately log the new state.  fooFunc will always log state before we added 1.  We can put any async await/then/setTimeout we want between setMyState and the log and we will always get the stale state.  That is because changes in state are only available on the next render of the component. But fooFunc was called before that re-render and it can't await for the next re-render because fooFunc was called in this render of the component.
